# Nativescript app tries to load a npm module from the wrong path

Tags: javascript, npm, nativescript

This is a problem I'm facing with 2 modules I installed through npm (tns add plugin produces the same error).

```
Oct 24 13:27:00 mbp mobile[83478]: file:///app/tns_modules/ui/builder/builder.js:167:56: JS ERROR Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/main-page.xml:18:11
 ↳Building UI from XML. @file:///app/mainTabs/tabNews/tabNews.xml:6:20
   ↳Module 'ui/fab' not found for element 'Fab'.
   ↳Could not find module 'ui/fab'. Computed path '/Users/foo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<device id>/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/<app id>/mobile.app/app/tns_modules/ui/fab'.
```

The path (including "tns_modules") is wrong. I don't even have a directory named tns_modules.

The modules are installed in the directory nodes_modules/, at its root.

I have some other plugins installed that work fine.

I have tried to:

- delete the platform/ directory
- delete the app from the emulator
- tns plugin add
- tns build ios
- tns run ios

This didn't solve the problem.

The plugins are:

https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-floatingactionbutton
and 
https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-pulltorefresh

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is how I call the plugin in my XML:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:x="nativescript-statusbar" actionBarHidden="false" loaded="loaded" xmlns:FAB="nativescript-floatingactionbutton">
```

Then in this page I have a tabView.
Each tab is in a separate file (through distinct namespaces).

Here's the code of the tab where I'm trying to add the floating button:

```
<GridLayout rows="auto, *">   
<ListView id="news-feed" items="{{ news }}" loaded="onLoaded" itemLoading="onItemLoading" separatorColor="#f4f4f4" class="newsfeedView">
   <ListView.itemTemplate>
   <GridLayout class="gridView">
   </GridLayout>
   </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
<FAB:fab tap="fabTap"
                 row="1"
                 icon="res://ic_add_white"
                 rippleColor="#f1f1f1"
                 class="fab-button" /></GridLayout>
```

Comment: tns_modules exists but its only inside applications at devices/simulator it's partially content of node_modules without some certain node_modules but it would be good to put your code for xml how did you import libraries :)

Comment: @MarekMaszay done!

Comment: Hi Dailyrox, the problem is that you have missed to add `xmlns:x="nativescript-statusbar"` in the open `GridLayout` tag in the XML file, where you are creating the UI for your tab. Then the app will know, where to search the plugin's custom component

Comment: @NikolayTsonev That doesn't seem to solve the problem. Plus, the statusbar plugin actually do work!

Comment: @Dailyrox I made a mistake in my previous comment, you should add `xmlns:FAB="nativescript-floatingactionbutton"` in open GridLayout tag in the XML file.

Comment: @NikolayTsonev thanks! I obviously corrected that when I spotted it :) and that's what I was referring as not working. The author of the plugins mentioned that the problem might come from the version of my cocoapods..